# 32 and 64 bit on one live USB stick

Tags: grub2, live-usb

I have successfully created a bootable Live USB stick on an 8Gb drive with either the 32 and 64 bit version of 11.10 but not bother at the same time.  I would like to put them both on the same stick along with a third distribution (DSL) so I only have to carry one drive.  How do I modify the GRUB files to make this happen?

Comment: Why do you want a 32-bit and 64-bit on the same USB-stick? If you run 64-bit then you can run all the 32-bit apps as well. **You don't need 2 systems.**

Comment: Are you trying to merge 2 versions into the same or have you devided the usb-stick in partitions? It would help to know...

Comment: I use this stick to boot up a Linux environment on various computers at my work (with permission). Some will not boot the 64 bit version to spite a sticker that says "Intel Core 2 Duo."  Others have enough ram that the 64-bit version is needed to take full advantage.  I only want to carry one stick.

Comment: Then the easiest is to make 2 partitions of the usb stick and then install the isos. It's confusing ask the question, I suggest you improve and clarifies your question.

Comment: Alvar, yes that was confusing.  I have tried to clarify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can see why one might want both, especially if you take it around to multiple machines and it's for testing purposes.

For my multiboot sticks I use a program called [Multisystem](http://liveusb.info/dotclear/).
It takes care of the grub configuration for you and makes it easy to remove and add various distros.

Comment: It's too bad the whole site is in French, but Google translate seems to do ok with it.

Answer (score 3):

There is a document describing how to do this on the Ubuntu wiki:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Dev/MultipleISOBootUSBKey

Basically, you configure grub to show a menu of .iso images on the USB device, "loopback mount" the right one, then boot from that.